# ggplot2: how to plot in reciprocal scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use ggplot to create scatter plot where y scale to be scaled as `1/y` (my y are all positive), yet labeled with original values of `y`.  How can I do this?

I tried to plot with `+ scale_y_continuous(trans='recip')` but got following error:

> Error in get(as.character(FUN), mode = "function", envir = envir) :
>   object 'recip_trans' of mode 'function' was not found

Thanks,

Comment: `?scales::reciprocal_trans` might be what you're looking for.

Comment: library(scales)...  correct?  Now i am trying to show the scale, i just got number reversed without any scale.  My original value is ranging from 700 to something like 5000.  so i want to draw lines like 500, 1000, 2000, 5000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

df = data.frame(x = c(1:46), y = seq(500, 5000, 100))

ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
   geom_point() +
    scale_y_continuous(trans = reciprocal_trans(), breaks = c(500, 1000, 2000, 5000))
```

[image]

Comment: Looks great!   thanks!!  I thought I needed something like `breaks=trans_breaks(function(x) 1/x, function(x) 1/x)(c(500,1000,2000,5000))` but yours was what I wanted!

Comment: I am wondering though how I was supposed to find this solution....?  Google and here is my only help.  Do I need to sit down with a book?

Comment: @yosukesabai Two sites that I find useful: for `scales` [github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/scales](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/scales), and for `ggplot2` [http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/docs/](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/docs/)

Comment: @yosukesabai And [Changes and Additions to ggplot2-0.9.0](http://cloud.github.com/downloads/hadley/ggplot2/guide-col.pdf)